# Multiple passphrase volume decryption on Linux

Tags: linux, encryption, luks

Is there any way to decrypt a volume that's been encrypted using a "standard" or commonly used volume encryption system (such as LUKS) using multiple passphrases? I've been searching for something that could do it, but haven't found anything indicating it's possible.

If there isn't a way of doing this natively with LUKS, I'm wondering if anyone has tried to build a custom way of doing it - possibly storing the volume decryption key / passphrase in an encrypted file that can be decrypted by multiple users (e.g. `gpg --encrypt --recipient user1 --recipient user2 luks-passphrase.txt`) - how would one go about about automating prompts to decrypt on boot?

Brief background on the use-case: I want to configure a workstation that a number of users can log on to. `/home` is to be encrypted, but I don't want to use a shared key to distribute between users - each user should be able to boot and log into the system using private, non-shared credentials.

If LUKS won't work, then I'd look at [GPG encrypted loopback disks | Patrick Uiterwijk Blog](http://patrick.uiterwijk.org/2013/02/25/gpg-encrypted-loopback-disks/) as an alternative system.

Answer (score 2):

So this feature is natively available in cryptsetup. e.g.

```
# cryptsetup luksAddKey --key-slot 1 /dev/sda2
```

Comment: Up to 8 keys keyslot 0 is the defacto and goes thru slot 7 0->7 = 8 slots